# Installation stuck on "Initializing Required Components" when trying to install Adobe Audition 3.0

Tags: installation, adobe

I have installed adobe audition 3.0 using wine. The problem is that, when I am trying to launch it gets stuck on Initializing Required Components when it's loading. What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do with any Wine trouble is to look up the application on [appdb.winehq.org](http://appdb.winehq.org/). It is a really good, community-run database of Windows applications and their compatibility with Wine. From the page on [Adobe Audition 3](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=13421), and [the trial version](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=13095), we can see that people have reported it partly working with Ubuntu 10.04, but there is some extra work involved to reach that point. There is a link to an article describing the extra steps to run Audition in Ubuntu 10.04, but it's a little outdated at this point. This should be a little easier now.

Open the Terminal application, and try the following…

Make sure winetricks is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

Now, run the following command:

```
winetricks corefonts vcrun6 mfc40 gdiplus
```

(You can also do that by opening Winetricks from the dash and selecting the components under "Install a windows DLL or component", but the command is a little quicker to deal with).

Try to run Adobe Audition, now. If it still doesn't work, open the "Configure Wine" application, or type `winecfg` in the terminal. First, in the Applications tab, select the exe file for Audition. (You will have to walk through the file system). Now click the Libraries tab, and add an override for gdiplus.dll.